# how to keep the content and behaviour of a modal in redux store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a confirmation dialog that is going to be used by the entire app, it is declared at the most high hirarchy component. it is connected to redux so everytime a component wants to open this modal, it updates the redux state with the message to be shown and the action to be dispatched again on confirm. It works, but the actions are not always plain objects, sometimes it is a function to handle async operations. I read that it is not recommended to store functions in the redux state, so what could I do instead?

Find below my component

```
const ConfirmDialog = 
    ({ isOpen, message, action, dispatchAction, setOpen }) => {

    const close = () => {
        setOpen(false);
    }

    const confirm = () => {
        dispatchAction(action);
        close();
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Dialog
                open={isOpen}
                aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
                aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
            >
                <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">
                    {"Are you sure?"} 
                </DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent>
                    <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
                        {message}
                    </DialogContentText>
                </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>
                    <Button onClick={confirm} color="primary">
                        confirm
                    </Button>
                    <Button onClick={close} color="primary"autoFocus>
                        cancel
                    </Button>
                </DialogActions>
            </Dialog>
        </div>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    isOpen: Selector.isOpen(state),
    message: Selector.getMessage(state),
    action: Selector.getAction(state)
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        setOpen: open => dispatch(Action.setOpen(open)),
        dispatchAction: action => dispatch(action)
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ConfirmDialog);
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirements. If you would like to share the same confirmation behavior among many components, you should put it in Redux. 
Otherwise, you could also do so simply by props:

```
class Dialog extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div className="dialog-wrapper">
                <div className="dialog-description">
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
                <button type="button" className="dialog-confirm-btn" onClick={this.props.confirmHandler}>Confirm</button>
                <button type="button" className="dialog-cancel-btn" onClick={this.props.cancelHandler}>Cancel</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

<Dialog 
confirmHandler={()=>{console.log('confirm')}}
cancelHandler={()=>{console.log('cancel')}}>
    are you sure?
</Dialog>
```

I personally usually use props to do so, so that the dialog can be re-used for all scenario

Comment: my dialog component looks like this, but the confirmHandler varies a lot, that is why I want to put it in redux. The question is, is it correct to put functions in redux? this.props.confirmHandler is going to be a function retrieved from redux

Comment: okay, and how do you set and retrieve the confirm behavior in your modal as props?

Comment: I would say it is not necessary to put it in Redux. In my case, I would set and retrieve my handlers in the component I use <Dialog/>. But if you want to make it even better, you may create a class and put all your dialog handlers in, so that you could retrieve the handler from everywhere. Let's see if anybody got a better suggestion

Comment: I intend to have only one <Dialog/> in the app, so it is going to be declared at a most high component in the app... say I have a functionality (delete record) in some nested component, how am I going to pass this props to the Dialog? If it was declared next to the component that causes it to open, I can not have just one dialog

Comment: I just saw your updated question, your design makes sense, but usually we'll store only data (like string, object, integer...) in the Redux store. If you would like to control the callback function by Redux, maybe you could store a flag/Enum in the Redux store? Then you could map the flag/Enum to another class which stores all the callbacks you have.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can keep the content and behavior of a modal in the redux store. 
You can create a component for the dialog box and pass the props to it such as when it should be shown, what will be done on a click of confirming and what on cancel.

As you are using redux you need to have relevant actions to confirm and cancel button's click so that it will make changes in the global redux state

Comment: can what will be done on a click of confirming be the reference to a function? I think it is not right to store non-serializable stuff in redux. I can not think of another approach, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Making it a function won't be suitable. U need to have an action which should at last make changes to the redux state so that you will be able to open and close the dialog on click of button.
If you wanna have function and you want to perform some changes in that component, than you can do one thing like, you can call the function of the component and do all the local stuff before calling action from that function.

Comment: I dont think I follow you. basically I have a button somewhere called "delete item". when I click this button, I open the confirmation dialog. managing the open and close is easy, but how can I proceed with the "delete action" on confirmation? how can I tell the confirm button to do that? if the modal is declared locally, I just passed it as props, but if it is one global component, how can I do so? I may use this dialog for other purposes, like "are you sure you want to empty your cart?" then the confirm button should perform another operation

Comment: Okay. I am not sure whether this works in ur project or not. But one thing you can do is you can have different actions for different functioanlity. For example: when deleting you can call action which deletes, empty action for emptying the cart or so? It would be more helpful if you share you code or relatable demo so that structure can be known